# I have gotten error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" when using axios in redux saga

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, redux-saga

The problem is that when I don't send `userId` to fetch data from database in redux saga, for example it works fine in this case:

```
export function* fetchUserFromDb() {
  const res = yield axios.get(`/api/employees/`);

  yield put(fetchUserSuccess({ res }));
}
```

But when I do this using `axios` with `userid`,

```
export function* fetchUserFromDb({ payload }) {
  const userId = payload;

  const res = yield axios.get(`/api/employees/${userId}`);

  yield put(fetchUserSuccess({ res }));
}
```

I got an error saying:

```
index.js:1 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

My server didn't show me any error so I guess the error happened in the front-end.

Is there anyone who knows why this is happening?

Comment: Could you please console the res which you are getting in both the cases, it would be then easier to debug,

Comment: wow!!! brilliant, this definitely helped my solve the issue.thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help Shawn if you could upvote me that would be great

Comment: I'd love to ! but I am new here, so not quite sure how to do that, could you tell me how to do?

Comment: @Shawn the button pointing upwards next to the comment.